# Swift crash when non-force unwrapping optionals?

Tags: ios, swift

I've got a crash with the following stack trace.

```
MAIN THREAD - CRASHED

libsystem_kernel.dylib    __pthread_kill
libsystem_c.dylib         abort
libswiftCore.dylib        swift::fatalError(unsigned int, char const*, ...)
libswiftCore.dylib        getNonNullSrcObject(swift::OpaqueValue*, swift::TargetMetadata<swift::InProcess> const*, swift::TargetMetadata<swift::InProcess> const*)
libswiftCore.dylib        tryCast(swift::OpaqueValue*, swift::TargetMetadata<swift::InProcess> const*, swift::OpaqueValue*, swift::TargetMetadata<swift::InProcess> const*, swift::TargetMetadata<swift::InProcess> const*&, swift::TargetMetadata<swift::InProcess> const*&, bool, bool)
libswiftCore.dylib        swift_dynamicCast
App                       function signature specialization <Arg[0] = Dead> of App.ImageViewingPageController.pageViewController(_: __C.UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfter: __C.UIViewController) -> __C.UIViewController? ImageViewingPageController.swift:90
App                       merged @objc App.ImageViewingPageController.pageViewController(_: __C.UIPageViewController, viewControllerBefore: __C.UIViewController) -> __C.UIViewController?
UIKitCore                 -[UIPageViewController _viewControllerBefore:viewController:]
UIKitCore                 -[UIPageViewController _queuingScrollView:viewBefore:view:]
UIKitCore                 -[_UIQueuingScrollView _viewBefore:view:]
UIKitCore                 -[_UIQueuingScrollView _requestViewForIndex:]
UIKitCore                 -[_UIQueuingScrollView _viewAtIndex:loadingIfNecessary:updatingContents:animated:]
UIKitCore                 -[_UIQueuingScrollView _didScrollWithAnimation:force:]
UIKitCore                 -[_UIQueuingScrollView _didScrollWithAnimation:force:]
UIKitCore                 -[_UIQueuingScrollView layoutSubviews]
UIKitCore                 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:]
QuartzCore                CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*)
QuartzCore                CA::Layer::layout_and_display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*)
QuartzCore                CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*, double, double*)
QuartzCore                CA::Transaction::commit()
QuartzCore                CA::Transaction::flush_as_runloop_observer(bool)
CoreFoundation            __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__
CoreFoundation            __CFRunLoopDoObservers
CoreFoundation            __CFRunLoopRun
CoreFoundation            CFRunLoopRunSpecific
GraphicsServices          GSEventRunModal
UIKitCore                 -[UIApplication _run]
UIKitCore                 UIApplicationMain
App                       main AppDelegate.swift:16
```

Line 90 referred to in the stack trace is the first line of `func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfter viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController?` implementation:

```
if let currentIndex = (viewController as? HasMediaInfo)?.mediaInfo?.index {
```

The types referred to in the line are

```
protocol HasMediaInfo {
    var mediaInfo: MediaInfo? { get set }
}

struct MediaInfo {
    let url: URL
    let index: Int
}
```

I'm completely puzzled what could be crashing in here.

Comment: The crash doesn't seem to be related to optionals. It seems to be about an attempt to perform the cast.

Comment: Could be, but how come is `(viewController as? HasMediaInfo)?` unsafe?

Comment: @MaciejTrybiło - break up the line while debugging to find out exactly where the error is occurring.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've found the issue. It's in fact possible for `viewController` to be `nil` if the page view controller had not been initialised with any pages and then the cast crashes when the user swipes. Changing the signature of the delegate call to `func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfter viewController: UIViewController?) -> UIViewController?` (add `?` after `viewController: UIViewController`) exposes this possibility to Swift.

Comment: But the signature of that delegate method does not declare the `viewController` parameter as optional. That's an issue if UIKit is passing a `nil` value to a non-optional parameter. You should make a minimal app that demonstrates the issue and submit a bug report to Apple.